# What is the direction of linear motion after this impact?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics

I've been thinking about a situation where I am not sure what the resulting motion would be.

This is what I am thinking,
[image: Ball Motion]

1) P is the point of application of force. If there are two force components N and R and T is the total force, which direction the ball will move in? It will accelerate parallel to N or it will accelerate parallel to T? Neglect any other forces such as friction, not shown in the figure.

2) If there is no friction at all, will the ball spin?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) The ball is going to move in the direction of T because that is the direction of the net force on the object. An intuition is if you were to rub the ball with your hand upward. You push a forward little bit and apply a normal force in the N direction, friction would cause the component in the R. From my experience, this makes it obvious enough to me why it would move along T.

2) The ball will also spin because there is a force component R in the perpendicular direction to a vector going from the center of mass to the point P and thus a torque.

Answer (score 0):

Objects accelerate in the direction of applied force  ($\vec{F} = m\vec{a}$).  Assuming the object begins at rest, then it (or its center of mass) must eventually be moving in the same direction as the net force.  This is parallel to $T$.

> If there is no friction at all, will the ball spin?

For a "smooth" surface, we assume that it can only provide normal forces and friction forces.  Any forces tangent to the surface ($R$ in your diagram) are due to friction.

By declaring there is no friction, then you are saying $R$ is zero.  In that case, the only remaining force ($N$) is on a line through the center of mass where it can create no torque and no rotational acceleration.